# DW01-AG circuit disabled

Tags: battery-operated, circuit-protection

I wonder what's wrong with my circuit. Voltage between VIN and GND is 0.5V instead supposed 3.3V.

Is there design issue? Assembly was maded by JLCPCB

VIN voltage: stable 3.3V from PSU (VIN - B_GND) (testing purposes)
VIN: Battery plus pin
B_GND: Battery ground pin
GND: Circuit ground

Schema:
[image]

PCB:
[image]

Comment: _"Voltage between VIN and GND is 0.5V"_ and _"VIN voltage: stable 3.3V from PSU (testing purposes)"_ is contradictory. Which is it?

Comment: @winny thanks for point! Edited. Output pins of PSU are VIN and B_GND.

Comment: How are GND and B_GND connected? Your OD signal will have no say since G1 is referenced to B_GND. I suspect you have built a source follower. Can you draw your Q2 as two MOSFETs instead? What are you trying to accomplish by separating the grounds?

Comment: @winny schema updated. GND and B_GND are connected via 8205A (I suppose).

Comment: Yes, but why? What are you trying to accomplish by separating the grounds?

Comment: @winny that's a battery protection circuit, it is supposed to separate the grounds to disconnect the battery when needed. This circuit may just have a slight error so it does not work.

Comment: Disconnect the battery yes, but why on the ground side of things? You are making it 10x more challenging to yourself. Ask yourself "when needed" is! Can the battery ground be hard tied to ground but the battery+ be floating?

Comment: Most battery protection ICs disconnect ground instead of power for some reason. See BQxxxxx series from TI and the DW01a used here that is super popular. In this instance, I don't think OP has a choice as to whether to switch power or ground without changing IC.

Comment: @syntax Whoa! What an interesting solution. Enables NFETs without any charge pump but does not allow the system to measure the battery voltage once disconnected.

Comment: @winny I guess like said Justme. If I merge B_GND to GND then red layer is merged aswell and battery will be connected. Perhaps its just editor issue that forces me to name it something else than "GND" (using Easyeda)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 looking into datasheets. I connected OD to G1, OC to G2. Thats not correct?

Comment: Oops my bad, just drawn weird instead of normal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRNNv.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 updated schematic. Is it alright by design? Where could be error?

Comment: Lots of design inconsistencies makes it harder to read. Like Q2 and of course missing Q1 silkscreen shud be U# not Q# and missing pins on schematic, and hard to read Gerber plot for grounds and isolation from outlines etc... non-std layout, shud have just copied existing designs, not sure where battery and charger are connected outside this clip.. Have you done any measurements for shorts? It seems you have I=(3.3-0.5)/100 = 27 mA load from an almost short with low Vgs

Comment: Smells like the floating Vbat- is grounded somewhere ;). SMT discrete pad gaps too small? Maybe a solder bridge under C1?  use OEM pad design for their solder process, reflow , forced hot air or whatever

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I dont use charger at all on my design. I have to admit I am new to using DW01. Battery is charged via external device. Design above use battery just as power source. I did some measuring. OD has 0 V, OC has 4 V (battery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick to enable circuit based on NOTE inside [different datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1351430/Fortune/DW01-G/1) page 8/14 second red note:

> Note: When a battery is connected to
> DW01-G for the first time, it may not enter
> the normal condition (dischargeable may
> not be enabled). In this case, short the CS
> and VSS pins or connect to a charger to
> restore to the normal condition

This trick enables circuit to work properly. However it's disappointing you have to short it every time battery is plugged-in.

I wonder how to avoid shorting VSS x CS every time I plug battery? Important note: Circuit is not charging battery! DW01 is used as overdischarge protection.